# about "Task Completion API" in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Can any one brief me about "task completion API" as i heard this will help in making the background task completion in Iphone projects..
And please give me the any samples on "Task Completion API", as problem in my project is when sending mail through SMTP there is no problem in foreground sending but am not able to send the mail when switch over foreground to background(ie switching over to other application in iphone4) while sending...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documents for the NSOperationQueue class.

Comment: please tell me how to use Task Completion API to be used in  NSOperationQueue

Answer (score 0):

There's a good section [in the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW12) about it. There is even sample code there.